# Regex capture set of groups that might or might not exist

Tags: java, regex

I have a bit of problem working with regex grouping.
Lets say i have the following string :

```
"Test, some information, more stuff (addtional information)"
```

I want to split this into 4 groups as the following:

```
group1: Test
group2: some information
group3: more stuff
group4: additional information
```

However group 2 may or may not exist and the same with group 4.

```
example:
"Test, more stuff" (group 2 and 4 don't exist)
"Test, some informattion, more stuff" (group 4 don't exist)
"test, more stuff (additional information)" (group 2 dont exist)
```

What I'ved started:

```
(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\\((.*?)\\)
```

How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `string.split`.

```
String s = "Test, some information, more stuff (addtional information)";
String parts[] = s.split(",\\s+|\\s*[()]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[Test, some information, more stuff, addtional information]
```

`\s+` matches one or more spaces.

OR

You could split your input according to `"\\s*[,()]\\s*"` regex suggested by our mod.

OR

make the 2 and 4 group as optional.

```
"^(.*?)(?:,(.*?))?,([^()\\n]*)(?: \\((.*?)\\))?$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iZ5kC7/5)

Comment: I think your split is the best approach. OP's grouping was just an attempt at a solution, but not as useful. You may consider `"\\s*[,()]\\s*"`